# External PHP file & Pretty Permalink

Tags: permalinks, wp-load.php

I'm working in developing REST API for a WP based website. Endpoint is `http://example.com/api.php` I've included `wp-load.php` in the top of the file to access WP functions etc.

However, `http://example.com/api.php` is loading normally in browser (not output as no parameter is passing). When I'm passing any parameters like `http://example.com/api.php?items=books` I'm WordPress getting non found error page.

Most wired part is, when I've disabling Pretty Permalink, everything is working normal.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and use code formatting for example links and use `http://example.com`, which is the default domain for examples. Thanks.

Comment: @kaiser, do you have any idea what is going on in my system?

Comment: _"I've included wp-load.php in the top of the file (...)"_ is what causing you the main issues. You are practically bypassing WP. Just search and read on other questions that include `wp-load.php` to find answers on how to do it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't say I've ever tried including `wp-load.php` directly, but I've had success using:

```
define("WP_USE_THEMES", false);
include("wp-blog-header.php");
```

... when trying to invoke Wordpress stack in a non-templated workflow.  `wp_blog_header.php` does make the call out to `wp-load.php` but also wires up some other stuff (such as calling `wp()`).